# Importance of instances of classes in python

Tags: python, class, instance

I do not understand the importance of instance when I create a class. In a book about Python programming I have found this example about the creation of a class that converts measure units:
The class parameters are therefore initial units, the new units and the factor of conversion.

```
class ScaleConverter:
       def __init__(self, units_from, units_to, factor):
       self.units_from = units_from
       self.units_to = units_to
       self.factor = factor

       def description(self):
           return "Convert " + self.units_from + "to" + self.units_to

       def convert(self, value):
           return value * self.factor

c1 = ScaleConverter("inches", "mm", 25)
```

So, I do not understand what could happen if I leave out `c1 = ScaleConverter("inches", "mm", 25)`
I have tried to clear it and classes works anyhow. What is its importance?

Comment: In what sense "works"?

Comment: `have tried to clear it and classes works anyhow`, please explain.

Comment: @khelwood runs without errors. I'm not quite sure what I need to explain to OP, as I'm struggling to understand how he/she does not understand.

Comment: Looks like you need to read the docs: [The Python Tutorial: 9. Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: I can't possibly see how this "works" without any errors, since it wouldn't do anything at all. Yes there'd be no errors, but there'd be no output or action either.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation: "have tried to clear it and classes works" I mean that I can use methods anyway, so I have noticed it is not foundamental for the class creation and usage.

Answer (score 1):

The line `c1 = ScaleConverter("inches", "mm", 25)` creates an instance of the class `ScaleConverter`. Without that line you're defining a class but you're not creating an instance - so you're not effectively doing anything. A class describes what instances of that class look like.

To use a class definition, you create instances of that class:

```
c1 = ScaleConverter("inches", "mm", 25)

c2 = ScaleConverter("meters", "cm", 100)
```

In the above, you now have two different instances (`c1` and `c2`) of the class `ScaleConverter` and you can use them in the rest of your code. That's the difference between classes and instances: a class is like a blueprint and an instance is an actual thing that was made using that blueprint.

Comment: But when I leave out the instance, I can "load" the class in the shell as: A = ScaleConverter('meters', 'cm', 100) and I can use methods with A without the instance

Comment: @Orlok: `A` is an instance in that case, it's just that you've used a variable with a capital letter. It's no different from `a = ScaleConverter('meters', 'cm', 100)`.

Comment: So the question is: When I create a class in a separate file to import in a "main" as a module, must I include the instance in the file class.py?

Comment: @Orlok: no, it's very common to have only class definitions in a file. You would import the class from that other file and then instantiate the class at the point where you're going to use it. So you would 'from module import MyClass' and then in your code: `a = MyClass()` to create an instance. After that you can use the instance.

Comment: Yes but I am not forced to insert `a = MyClass()` in the file of the class, am I? But in that case I have to instantiate the class in the main script as `a = MyClass()` in order to use it, right?

Answer (score 1):

Please review the official docs.

Using the notiation

```
c1 = ScaleConverter("inches", "mm", 25)
```

Creates a new `ScaleConverter` object and assigns it to your `c1` variable.

A class definition by itself is just a blueprint for how to create an instance. Think of it as a schema or a contract that an object abides by.

---

## [9.3.2. Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

Class objects support two kinds of operations: attribute references and instantiation.

*Attribute references* use the standard syntax used for all attribute references in Python: `obj.name`. Valid attribute names are all the names that were in the class’s namespace when the class object was created. So, if the class definition looked like this:

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

then `MyClass.i` and `MyClass.f` are valid attribute references, returning an integer and a function object, respectively. Class attributes can also be assigned to, so you can change the value of `MyClass.i` by assignment. `__doc__` is also a valid attribute, returning the docstring belonging to the class: "A simple example class".

Class *instantiation* uses function notation. Just pretend that the class object is a parameterless function that returns a new instance of the class. For example (assuming the above class):

```
x = MyClass()
```

creates a new instance of the class and assigns this object to the local variable x.

Comment: Not sure what the point is of this huge copy-and-paste from the documentation.

Comment: But I can create an instance also out of the class every time I assign a variable for the class. For example I can create an instance in the shell as A = ScaleConverter('a', 'b', 2) without specifying it in the class object creation, right ?

Comment: Everything you need to know is in Chapter 9.

Answer (score 1):

**By using instance of object you can use same class for different operation.**

A class is a kind of factory  for constructing objects. The non-static parts of the class specify, or describe, what variables and methods the objects will contain. **This will explain how objects differ from classes:** Objects are created and destroyed as the program runs, and there can be many objects with the same structure, if they are created using the same class.

c1 = ScaleConverter("inches", "mm", 25)

Here c1 is a instance object of class ScaleConverter. So you can create other object if you want to use other parameters for same code.

Answer (score 0):

ScaleConverter is your class. c1 is an instance of that class.

When you run `c1 = ScaleConverter("inches", "mm", 25)`, you give c1 the properties of the class `ScaleConverter`

Now, you could do the following with c1, given that it is of the class `ScaleConverter`:

```
print c1.description
"Convert inches to mm"
print c1.convert(2)
"50"
```